# How to make react-native-maps animateCamera change heading from last heading to new heading

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

Is there any way I can make the map changes from last heading to a new heading?

```
  prev_heading = 100
  this.map.animateCamera({
     heading: 120 
  });
```

Current behaviour: The maps rotate from 0 deg to 120 deg

Expected behaviour: The maps rotate from 100 deg to 120 deg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. I need to use initialCamera props in MapView component instead of using initialRegion. Then I use animateCamera method to change the map coordinate and heading.